# Is there anyway to scale an area on the screen?

Tags: javascript

[image]

I've been working on a timer that shows you your age, and one of the things I want to implement now is make it so the seconds number 'bubbles' in size, or animates a size increase/decrease every second.

My problem is that I didn't know I was going to want this, and how I actually designed this initially was by having all of the numbers as one large string separated by spaces. So I have the scaling animation working, but it just scales all of the numbers, instead of just the seconds.

I know it isn't possible to make a portion of a string larger/smaller, but I was wondering if it was possible to take a portion of the entire view and increase/decrease the size of that

Comment: You must be thinking in terms of DOM elements and CSS styles, not in strings.

Comment: [`transform: scale(…)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) is what you are looking for. Combine that with some nifty CSS animation and you don't need JavaScript at all.

Comment: Sorry you're right.  Using this project as a way to learn javascript, still not quite used to everything.  would I just replace my use of 'string' with 'DOM element?'  or would 'DOM Text' make more sense?

Comment: [Here is the documentation on MDN for scaling in css](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform#scale), and [here is what browsers it works on](http://caniuse.com/#search=scale)

Comment: If you just want to animate the text, CSS animations and font-size are what you want, but I'm pretty sure font size doesn't animate smoothly.

Comment: @Bergi I've seen that, but it looks like I can only apply css scaling to a DOM element?  Is there anything I should be looking for in the documentation for scaling a specific, say square area on the entire view?

Comment: @JamesG. I specifically just want to animate a portion of the text, which is the problem.  Worst case I'm just going to split up my timer into separate elements w/ ids and then I'll be able to animate easily

Comment: No, splitting them up into single elements so that they can be animated separately is not the worst case, it is the proper solution. Notice that in the DOM there are no "square areas of view", there are only elements and their boxes. If you're looking to manipulate rectangles of pixels, then `<canvas>` would be the right thing for you (though probably overkill for this problem)

Comment: Not just the proper solution, the only one.